# Timing a broadcasted message to all processors using MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv instead of MPI_Bcast

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a project where I need to time any bad implementation of MPI_Bcast using MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv, and compare it against MPI_Bcast. Because the time on these programs is 0.000000 Seconds, I need to use a large array (as I have done). What is not yet in my code below is that the for loop and MPI_Irecv/Isend functions should be in a loop to make the program take a useful amount of time to finish.

Here is my code, and I'll discuss the problem I am having below it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int a = 1000000000;
  int i, N;
  int Start_time, End_time, Elapse_Time;
  int proc_rank, partner, world_size;
  MPI_Status stat;
  float mydata[a];
  MPI_Request request;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  Start_time = MPI_Wtime();

  for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    mydata[i] = 0.2567*i;
  }

  MPI_Irecv(mydata, a, MPI_BYTE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

  MPI_Isend(mydata, a, MPI_BYTE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

  End_time = MPI_Wtime();
  Elapse_Time = End_time - Start_time;
  printf("Time on process %d is %f Seconds.\n", proc_rank, Elapse_Time);

  MPI_Finalize;

return 0;
}
```

When I run this using the command `mpirun -np 4 ./a.out`, I only get the time for one processor, but I'm not really sure why. I guess I'm just not understanding how these functions work, or how I should be using them.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How large did you set the stack for your program? Most OS only provide few MiB, so `mydata[]` will **very** likely oveflow => undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what you mean by "set the stack." Changing the array size to smaller values seems to make the problem less likely to happen, but it still occasionally happens.

Comment: Is google down? Simply put: the array is **far** too large for an `auto` variable. Use a static variable, either at file-level - be it `static` or with external linkage or a local `static`. I did not say this was the only error. And think about the implications of "**undefined**".

Comment: What is the world_size value? Try to see if it's the same value than the number of process you run.

Comment: @CaptainWise It's the same value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different issues in your code, all likely to lead to it to crash and or to behave strangely:

- As already mentioned by @Olaf the allocation of the array `mydata` on the stack is a very bad idea. For arrays this large, you should definitely go for an allocation on the heap with an explicit call to `malloc()`. Even so, you are playing with some serious chunks of memory here, so be careful of not exhausting what's available on your machine. Moreover, some MPI libraries have difficulties to deal with messages of size greater than 2GB, which is the case of yours. So again, be careful with that.
- You use `mydata` for both sending and receiving purpose. However, once you posted a non-blocking communication, you **cannot reuse the corresponding message until the communication is finished**. So in your case, you'll need two arrays, one for sending and one for receiving.
- The type of the data you pass to your MPI calls, namely `MPI_BYTE`, isn't coherent with the actual type of the data you transfer, namely `float`. You should use `MPI_FLOAT` instead.
- You call `MPI_Irecv()` and `MPI_Isend()` without calling any valid `MPI_Wait()` or `MPI_Test()` functions. This is wrong since this means that the communications might never occur.
- `MPI_Wtime()` returns a `double`, not an `int`. This isn't an error *per se* but it might lead to unexpected results. Moreover, the format requested in your call to `printf()` corresponds to a floating point data, not an integer, so you have to make it coherent.
- (Minor - typo ) You missed the `()` for `MPI_Finalize()`.
- (Minor - I guess) You only communicate with process #0...

So here is some possible version of a working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int a = 1000000000;
    int i, from, to;
    double Start_time, End_time, Elapse_Time;
    int proc_rank, world_size;
    float *mysenddata, *myrecvdata;
    MPI_Request requests[2];

    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_rank );
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size );

    Start_time = MPI_Wtime();

    mysenddata = (float*) malloc( a * sizeof( float ) );
    myrecvdata = (float*) malloc( a * sizeof( float ) );

    assert( mysenddata != NULL ); /*very crude sanity check */
    assert( myrecvdata != NULL ); /*very crude sanity check */

    for ( i = 0; i < a; i++ ) {
        mysenddata[i] = 0.2567 * i;
    }

    from = ( proc_rank + world_size - 1 ) % world_size;
    to = ( proc_rank + 1 ) % world_size;

    MPI_Irecv( myrecvdata, a, MPI_FLOAT, from, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[0] );
    MPI_Isend( mysenddata, a, MPI_FLOAT, to, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[1] );
    MPI_Waitall( 2, requests, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE );

    End_time = MPI_Wtime();
    Elapse_Time = End_time - Start_time;
    printf( "Time on process %d is %f Seconds.\n", proc_rank, Elapse_Time );

    free( mysenddata );
    free( myrecvdata );

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

NB: for the sake of having a code working in all circumstances, I implemented a communication ring here, were process 0 sends to process 1 and receives from process size-1... However, in the context of your re-implementation of a broadcast, you can just ignore this (ie. the `from` and `to` parameters).

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helps. 

I'm just wondering - how do 'from' and 'to' work? 'to' makes it send to the proc_rank one above its own, and for 'from,' say the proc_rank=0, then it would be 0+3 % 4 = 3. So I'm confused about how 'to' is sending from one processor to all the others, and why we are defining 'from' like that. I'm guessing it has something to do with the functions MPI_Isend/MPI_Irecv, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: No, I simply implemented a ring here: 0->1, 1->2, ... N-1->0. This was a way of making sure that every process was sending to someone, and receiving from someone. In the context of your broadcast-like implementation, you can just ignore that.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that. I hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

The only explaination I see is your other process is crashing before the print. Try to put some part of your code in comment and reexecute the code.

Try this way and see if you see a difference

```
  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  /*Start_time = MPI_Wtime();

  for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    mydata[i] = 0.2567*i;
  }

  MPI_Irecv(mydata, a, MPI_BYTE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

  MPI_Isend(mydata, a, MPI_BYTE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

  End_time = MPI_Wtime();
  Elapse_Time = End_time - Start_time;*/
  printf("I'm process %d.\n", proc_rank);

  MPI_Finalize;
```

Comment: Oh, that seems right. When I do that, some of them don't print. And the variable `a` being large makes them crash more often. I'm just not sure how to fix this. Setting it as a static variable helps, but as mentioned above it's not the only error...

Comment: I meant there might be multiple reasons why it's crashing, although I'm not really sure why it's crashing

Comment: Try to use `SIZE_MAX` for your array size and your `a` variable.

Comment: I don't think other part making your code crash. Just try with a small array and see if all your process working.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using SIZE_MAX for the array size. I included `  printf("size max %zu\n", SIZE_MAX);` and the output was `size max 18446744073709551615`.
If I use a small array, they work most of the time, but occasionally one crashes. They also finish too quickly for me to time it.

Comment: SIZE_MAX usually is the maximum size of an array you can use, but depending on your compiler and your computer this value can vary. Try to use MPI_Send and MPI_Rec. MPI_Isend is a non-blocking call so it's why you always getting 0 for your delay.